Why is an async overload preventing my coalescing operator from working?
When I have an overloaded async function my nil coalescing operator seems to stop working as expected.
My example code I used in Playground:
public class Mock {
    public var values: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]

    public func retrieve<T>(key: String) -> T? {
        return values[key] as? T
    }

    public func retrieve<T>(key: String) async -> T? {
        return values[key] as? T
    }
}

let mock = Mock()
let a: Bool? = (mock.retrieve(key: "Test")) ?? false
let b: Bool? = ((mock.retrieve(key: "Test")) ?? false) ?? false
print(a)
print(b)

a is returning as nil and b is returning as false. I would expect a to be false as well. If I comment out the async function a returns false.

You are never calling the async function which can be easily verified by some print statements. The difference in the result is because of how you use parentheses.

So given that it's not clear what this question is about, if you want to call the async variant you need to call it in an asynchronous context for instance using a Task and prefixed with await.

@JoakimDanielson I think the issue is more complex than this. "If I comment out the async function a returns false." I've verified that. That's quite interesting,

The fact that it is different when you add the async method, IMO, is a compiler bug and I would suggest filing it at bugs.swift.org. But what is actually happening is more interesting, and points to the ambiguity of what you've written. The real problem isn't that this ambiguous code gives different results when small changes are made, it's that this ambiguous code is allowed at all. (Never write code this way.)
First, let's get a picture of what the compiler is actually doing. My preferred tool is swiftc -emit-sil:
godbolt
...
sil @main : $@convention(c) (Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> Int32 {
bb0(%0 : $Int32, %1 : $UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>):
  alloc_global @$s6output4mockAA4MockCvp, loc * "/app/example.swift":13:5, scope 1 // id: %2
  %3 = global_addr @$s6output4mockAA4MockCvp : $*Mock, loc * "/app/example.swift":13:5, scope 1 // users: %41, %11, %7
  %4 = metatype $@thick Mock.Type, loc "/app/example.swift":13:12, scope 3 // user: %6
  %5 = function_ref @$s6output4MockCACycfC : $@convention(method) (@thick Mock.Type) -> @owned Mock, loc "/app/example.swift":13:12, scope 3 // user: %6
  %6 = apply %5(%4) : $@convention(method) (@thick Mock.Type) -> @owned Mock, loc "/app/example.swift":13:12, scope 3 // user: %7
  store %6 to %3 : $*Mock, loc "/app/example.swift":13:12, scope 3 // id: %7
  alloc_global @$s6output1aSbSgvp, loc * "/app/example.swift":14:5, scope 3 // id: %8
  %9 = global_addr @$s6output1aSbSgvp : $*Optional<Bool>, loc * "/app/example.swift":14:5, scope 3 // users: %92, %32, %26
  %10 = alloc_stack $Optional<Optional<Bool>>, loc * "/app/example.swift":14:22, scope 5 // users: %21, %35, %19
...

Here (%10) is where things go sideways (according to what you probably wanted). The type of the expression is Bool??. This is the most reasonable return type for the compiler to pick. The final result should Bool?. So the natural thing to do is to promote false to Optional(false) and that means that the thing in parentheses should return Bool??. IMO, the bug is that when the async method is removed, this isn't still selected, since it's the most consistent (IMO) way to read this expression. It's how it's read in the second example, so you seem to expect this somewhat.
To the obvious next question of "how do I fix it," the first answer is "stop doing this." [String: Any] is ugly at best. Fetching from them using -> T? layers trouble upon trouble. Mixing Optionals and Any and unbounded generics will bite you every time.
If you must have a [String: Any], the better API is along these lines:
public func retrieve<T>(key: String, as: T.Type = T.self) -> T? {
    return values[key] as? T
}

public func retrieve<T>(key: String, default: T) -> T {
    return retrieve(key: key, as: T.self) ?? `default`
}

And stop doing things like assigning false to Bool?. Just stop that.
But you're correct. This does point to a compiler bug, and it's worth raising that. This code would ideally be rejected with an error, but if it must compile it should be consistent.
